# Swift SpriteKit unwrapping and wrapping

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, word-wrap

```
func bombTowerTurnShoot() {
let zombieGreen =  self.childNode(withName: "zombie") as! SKSpriteNode
    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "bomb tower") {
        node, stop in
            if let bombTower = node as? SKSpriteNode {
            let angle = atan2((zombieGreen.position.x) - bombTower.position.x, (zombieGreen.position.y) - bombTower.position.y)
            let actionTurn = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: -(angle - CGFloat(Double.pi/2)), duration: 0.2)
            bombTower.run(actionTurn)
                }
            }
        }
```

My issue is on the let angle line. When I call the function when there is no zombieGreens on the scene I get a Thread 1 problem. How can I change the code to take into account when the zombie is not present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if there is no ZombiGreens in the scene the error should happen already at the second line:

```
let zombieGreen =  self.childNode(withName: "zombie") as! SKSpriteNode
```

I think the simplest solution without changing to much of your code would be to use an **if let** just as you did for the bomb tower. and it would look something like this:

```
func bombTowerTurnShoot() {
            if let zombieGreen =  self.childNode(withName: "zombie") as? SKSpriteNode{
                self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "bomb tower") {
                    node, stop in
                    if let bombTower = node as? SKSpriteNode {
                        let angle = atan2((zombieGreen.position.x) - bombTower.position.x, (zombieGreen.position.y) - bombTower.position.y)
                        let actionTurn = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: -(angle - CGFloat(Double.pi/2)), duration: 0.2)
                        bombTower.run(actionTurn)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But it could be a good idea to review your code when you have more logic to handle. it might be a better way to do things but this should work :)

Comment: Note that we use **as?** instead of **as!**. ! will force the unwrap while ? would check if the value is something else then nil before unwrapping. if it is  nil it wont unwrap and you wont crash. unless you have something later in your code that is dependent on this value. To use an If let statement you must use ? (I'm almost 100% sure, correct me if I'm wrong)